# ASCII art troubles

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, english, word-game

Please look further only if you're 18+ and not of a sensitive disposition.

> [image: ascii-art-troubles]

The puzzle consists only of the image above. If it doesn't look sharp enough, you can click on it to enlarge it. There's no catch or clue in the image itself, it's really just a screenshot of some ASCII text (and line-drawing characters) to prevent distortions due to font rendering.

Minor hints I've given out in comments:

- > The first three text-only boxes are part of the puzzle and your solution must take them into account.
- > If the fifth picture depicted a honeymoon, that would *not* invalidate the puzzle.
- > "US" on the hoover from the sixth picture indicates "not British English".
- > In the the eighth (second to last) picture I did not intend to draw necessarily a "bun in the oven", i.e. a pregnancy, though that would fit nicely in the narrative without spoiling the puzzle. The figure's age and sex are unimportant.
- > The answer is not "I'm pregnant", though it may look like it.

Hints:

- > write them down, find what's repeating everywhere
- > the seventh box shows instructions for using a protective device, which in an informal setting may be called as the material it is made of

Comment: Congrats You are pregnant!

Comment: @Preet It may look like it, but no. I know many men try...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was single, now ...

> ... **I'm double**.

How is the message hidden in the ASCII art?

> Each scene describes a word that has a double letter. The double letters spell out the answer. In particular:
>
>  • ASC**II**
>  • A double apostrophe **''**
>  • a co**mm**a
>  • a we**dd**ing
>  • a h**oo**ker
>  • a vac**uu**m cleaner
>  • a ru**bb**er
>  • a be**ll**y
>  • b**ee**r

Comment: `"` is a double `'` :)

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that. `:(` I've added it to the explanation.

Comment: Anyhow, well done!

Comment: Oh, I liked the twist with the double quote. I just didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

*Caution: NSFW language ahead*

I was single, now...

> **Met up** (with someone)
>  **Hooked up** (the image represents the classic hooker solicitation pose)
>  **Sucked up** (vacuum cleaner, not sure what the US represents)
>  **Screwed up** (the image represents sex)
>  **Grew up** (it looks like the stick figure grew in height and width)
>  **Drunk up** (that's a beer mug)

In summary, I think the picture says something along the lines of:

> I was single, now I'm single and drunk.

Comment: You found an impressive unintended pattern with those "up" phrases! But I'm afraid it doesn't explain the first three, text-only boxes.
"US" represents "not British English".

Comment: @ngn ah, I didn't realize those first 3 boxes were also clues to be solved, I (wrongly) assumed they were part of the setup.

Answer (score 1):

> I was single, then came marriage, honeymoon, housework, sex, and finally either a bun in the oven and champagne, or too much beer and a pot belly. Hard to tell which.

Comment: too long; not enough coincidences to make a consistent theory; "honeymoon" is wrong and right at the same time; buns don't have handles; +1 for an optimistic view on my life :)

Comment: The 'bun in the oven' statement was for the second-last picture, with a large belly and an arrow pointing to it, not the beer mug.

Comment: oh, sorry... still, "bun" is not what I had in mind